# Retina images (@2x~ipad) not loaded if iPad image doesn't exist (~ipad)

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage, retina-display

I have something strange in my app.

If in the ressources I have 2 files named : **myFile~ipad.png** and **myFile@2x~ipad.png** the retina image is loaded on iPad retina as it should be.
But If i have two files named **myFile.png** and **myFile@2x~ipad.png**, the retina images is never loaded and **myFiles.png** is used for all devices.

Is this normal ? The problem is that I want to use the image **myFile.png** for iPhone, iPhone retina and iPad and the image **myFile@2x~ipad.png** for iPad retina so I can't put the extension ~ipad beyond myFile.png.

Comment: Might be a silly question, but why not have myFile~ipad.png myFiles.png? yes it is a duplicate, but one is for your OS resource which is automatically being used, and the other one is your own resource to use within the app.

Comment: The app is already pretty large and it would be much more larger...

Comment: Maybe a symlink? I just google it, and didn't say it couldn't be done, but most of it points to symlink in an SD card.

Comment: Symlink are working. Thanks ! Post an answer and I4ll put it as valid.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted. I have @2x~iPad and ~iPad images and Retina are not showing up. ANy help would be great?

Comment: Answer from Churk is working : use symlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use symlink. I just google it, and didn't say it couldn't be done, but most of it points to symlink in an SD card.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the same image "myFile.png" with different name as myFile~ipad.png so that you can have same result for iPhone, iPhone retina and iPad. And "myFile@2x~ipad.png" image for ipad retina display.

hope this will help.

Comment: hey if lots of images make your app too large. you can use this tool to reduce the size of images without losing quality of them. - 
http://imageoptim.com/

Hope this will reduce your app size.

Comment: Or write some macros to determine if(iPhone or iPad no-retina) then use this image, else use iPad retina.

Comment: @cerdicSoubrine Can i know what best solution you opted for? as i am also resolving the same issue within my app.

Answer (score 1):

We tried using symlinks, but it turns out that in the built app, the symlinks actually turned into copies of the images they linked to. Xcode resolves symlinks by copying the source file. So you can use symlinks for convenience, but not to save storage space in the built app.